# ¿Como seleccionar la ultima fila de mi DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net

Hola tengo un formulario donde al editar y regresar a la grilla si permanece seleccionado y en la vista previa de los datos puedo ver los datos de ese registro pero cuando le doy en la opcion guardar si selecciona la fila registrada pero en la vista previa no me muestra los datos de ese registro sino del primero del DataGridView.
Como podria hacer para que al momento que se guarde se seleccione y muestre los valores de la ultima fila seleccionada?

codigo

```
IF cmd.ExecutellonQuery() Then

MostrarDatos()

If pNuevo = True Then
Dim ultimafila As Integer
tbp = Nothing
tbp = New DataTable
pSql = " select idMaterial from Material Where Material"
Dim dap As New SqlDataAdapter(pSql, gConn)
dap.Fil1(tbp)
If tbp.Rows.Count <> 0 Then

pMaterial = ITF(IsDBNul1(tbp.Rows(0).Item("idMaterial")), 0, tbp.Rows(0).Item("idMaterial"))
End If

GrabarLogTransacciones ("Registrar", "frmlaterial", "Id material registrado")
Call MostrarMaterial()
Me. grdMaterial ClearSelection()
    
ultimafila = grdMaterial.RowCount - 1

Me. grdMaterial .Rows(ultimafila) Selected = True
Me.grdMaterial.Refresh()

Call MostrarDatos()

Else
Call MostrarMaterial()
Me.grdMaterial.ClearSelection()
Me.grdMaterial.Rows(index) .Selected = True
GrabarLogTransacciones("Actualizar”, "frmMaterial", "Id material modificado: " & lblIdMaterial.Text)
End If
End If

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Para seleccionar la última fila de tu DataGridView, podés usar este ejemplo:

```
If DataGridView1.RowCount > 0 Then
        Dim LastRow As Short = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index > 0 Then
            DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(LastRow).Cells(0)
            DataGridView1.Rows(LastRow).Selected = True
        End If
    End If
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda